# Android unicast UDP works but broadcast doesn't

Tags: java, android, python, udp

For an assignment, we're trying to set up multiple Android devices to receive an UDP broadcast from a laptop, over a local WiFi network.

What works:

- Python terminal's on two laptops are able to send and receive UDP broadcasts or unicasts to each other.
- Android devices can receive an UDP message sent directly to their IP

What doesn't work:

- Android device (LG/Google Nexus 4) does not receive the UDP broadcast message (the other laptop running Python does)

Any advice? Here's our source for each component (shamelessly borrowed from the internets)

**Python receive broadcast**

```
import select, socket

port = 50000
bufferSize = 1024

ip = '0.0.0.0'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((ip, port))

while True:
    msg, result = s.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    pr

int "Received message: ", msg
```

**Python send broadcast**

```
# Send UDP broadcast packets

port = 50000

import sys, time
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)

data = repr(time.time()) + '\n'
s.sendto(data, ('192.168.1.255', port))
```

**Android**

```
private void receiveUDP() {
    final String[] text = new String[1];
    final int server_port = 50000;
    // create buffer
    final byte[] message = new byte[1500];
    final DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);

    // listen for message, put in buffer
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Log.d(Main.class.getName(), "Created socket");
                    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
                    s.receive(p);
                    text[0] = new String(message, 0, p.getLength());
                    Log.d(Main.class.getName(), "message:" + text[0]);
                    s.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "An unexpected error occurred", e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

To reiterate, the only thing that doesn't work is receiving UDP broadcast on Android - it can receive individual UDP messages to its IP, and the Python terminal does receive UDP broadcast from the other laptop....

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

I see that we are supposed to use MulticastLock - I've now tried this and it still doesn't work. This is the new Android code:

```
private void receiveUDP() {
    final String[] text = new String[1];
    final int server_port = 50001;
    // create buffer
    final byte[] message = new byte[1500];
    final DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);

    // listen for message, put in buffer
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DatagramSocket s = null;
                while (true) {
                    try{
                        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("Main");
                        lock.acquire();
                        s = new DatagramSocket(server_port, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.13"));
                        Log.d(Main.class.getName(), "Created socket");
                            s.receive(p);
                        lock.release();
                        text[0] = new String(message, 0, p.getLength());
                        Log.d(Main.class.getName(), "message:" + text[0]);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Received message: "+text[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        Log.e(Main.class.getName(), "An unexpected error occurred", e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(Main.class.getName(), "An unexpected error occurred", e);
                    } finally {
                        if (s != null) s.close();
                        Log.d(Main.class.getName(), "Closing socket");
                    }
                }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do that too. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I did actually. The code is fine but some phones, including Nexus 4, lock down the UDP receive broadcast capability. The solution is to use a different phone. For example, it works on the inexpensive Huawei G300

Comment: Brand new Nexus 5 seems to have the same idiotic problem.... This is not carrier related since it's an unlock device from Google PlayStore. Thanks Alex for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some phones, including Nexus 4, lock down the UDP receive broadcast capability. The solution is to use a different phone. For example, it works on the inexpensive Huawei G300

Comment: I would love to know more about this, any links?